# NoMethodError for readbytes on Ruby File class

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.8

I am writing a script to read the header bytes from a PNG file.  I want to use the `readbytes` method on `File`:

```
f = File.open("Boots.png", "rb:binary")
header = f.readbytes(8)
```

But I get a `NoMethodError` on the second line:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `readbytes` for #<File:Boots.png>
    from (irb):2
    from #:0
```

Why?  As far as I can tell from the doc, `readbytes` is part of the `IO` class, parent to `File`, and should be available to me, without a require or include.  I am almost exactly following a sample in the David Flanagan guide; I can even find the source `readbytes.rb` file in my Ruby installation.

Note that I am running the MRI 1.8.7 on Windows 7.

Comment: You should not be using Ruby 1.8 at this time. You should switch to Ruby 2.0.

Comment: As it turns out ````read()```` works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`readbytes` isn't member of `IO` or `File` (where did you find the entry in the doc?). Use [`IO#read([length])`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/IO.html#method-i-read) to read bytes from file. And you may need [`String#unpack`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html#method-i-unpack) to convert the string to magic header you want to compare.

Comment: Looks like there was such method in [Ruby 1.8](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/readbytes/rdoc/IO.html). Perhaps it was deprecated in modern Ruby.

Comment: Thank you. @sawa, is there a way to definitely determine when it was deprecated?  Note that I need to use 1.8.7--in my environment I don't have a choice.

Comment: @WaveformDelta Check the available methods by doing `p File.methods`.